# Exception of Texture2D.FromMemory() in SharpDX code

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I'm studying the DirectX and SharpDX(use ver.2.6.2).

Now, I try to create a texture from byte array by using Texture2D.FromMemory() method.
My sample code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Windows;
using Buffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer;
using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;
using MapFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags;

namespace HLSLTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.Text = "D3DRendering - Test";
            form.Width = 640;
            form.Height = 480;

            Device device;
            SwapChain swapChain;

            var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,
                ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = form.Handle,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };

            Device.CreateWithSwapChain(
                SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware,
                DeviceCreationFlags.None,
                new[] {
                    SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_11_0,
                    SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_10_1,
                    SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_10_0,
                },
                desc,
                out device,
                out swapChain
            );

            // It's Ok, no error
            //var texture = Texture2D.FromFile<Texture2D>(device, "GeneticaMortarlessBlocks.jpg");

            // "An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll"
            // "Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80004005], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_FAIL/Unspecified error]"
            byte[] texArray = new byte[8];
            var texture = Texture2D.FromMemory(device, texArray);

            var textureView = new ShaderResourceView(device, texture);
        }
    }
}
```

However, my code occurrs the following exception.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll
Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80004005], Module: [General], ApiCode:[E_FAIL/Unspecified error], Message: エラーを特定できません
```

I search same problem or a solution on the web but I cannot find anything.

Please give me any advices.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a texture from a memory block like this. The method `Texture2D.FromMemory` is expecting the same kind of texture supported by `Texture2D.FromFile`, the only difference is that instead of reading from the disk, it can read from memory.

Creating a texture from a raw memory block requires to create a new `Texture2D()` from a `Texture2DDescription` of the texture and a memory region of the data through the `DataRectangle` structure. This description includes the width, height, the pixel format, the number of mips, number of arrays...etc.  The equivalent native method is [ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476521.aspx).

In the end, the D3DX functions like `Texture2D.FromFile/FromMemory` are using the same `ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D` to create a texture.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

I try to modify my code with the Texture2DDescription.