# Texture2d from Byte array Sharpdx

Tags: c#, arrays, sharpdx, texture2d

I am a C#, SharpDX and Directx newbie. Please excuse my ignorance. I am following up on an old post: [Exception of Texture2D.FromMemory() in SharpDX code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720340/exception-of-texture2d-frommemory-in-sharpdx-code/24725290#24725290?newreg=4e2a99c0314042a7abe606a48e42442b). It was very helpful.

**My goal:**

1. Build a Texture2d from softwarebitmap.
2. Make the texture available to HLSL.

**The way I approached it:**

1. Using IMemoryBufferByteAccess, I was able to retrieve the pointer to byte and the total capacity of Frame. From the previous post, it seems I would need to use the DataRectangle to point to the byte array.
2. Have 2 textures with different descriptors- Texture1 (_staging_texture)- none binding flag, cpu write and read privileges, usage- staging. I created this texture with the datarectangle pointing to the byte array. Texture2 (_final_texture)- Shader binding flag, no cpu access, usage- default. This texture would be eventually made available to the shader. The intention was to use the copyResource function from Texture1 to Texture2.

Below, I copy my unpolished code for reference:

```cs
               bitmap = latestFrame.SoftwareBitmap;
                Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapBuffer bitmapBuffer= bitmap.LockBuffer(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapBufferAccessMode.Read);
                Windows.Foundation.IMemoryBufferReference bufferReference = bitmapBuffer.CreateReference();
                var staging_descriptor = new Texture2DDescription
                {
                    Width = Width,
                    Height = Height,
                    MipLevels = 1,
                    ArraySize = 1,
                    Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
                    SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
                    Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
                    BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
                    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read | CpuAccessFlags.Write,
                    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
                };
                var final_descriptor = new Texture2DDescription
                {
                    Width = Width,
                    Height = Height,
                    MipLevels = 1,
                    ArraySize = 1,
                    Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
                    SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
                    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                    BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
                    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
                };

                var dataRectangle = new SharpDX.DataRectangle();
                unsafe
                {
                    byte* dataInBytes;
                    uint capacityInBytes;
                    ((InteropStatics.IMemoryBufferByteAccess)bufferReference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacityInBytes);                    
                    dataRectangle.DataPointer = (IntPtr)dataInBytes;
                    dataRectangle.Pitch = 4;
                }
                

                Texture2D _stagingTexture = new Texture2D(device, staging_descriptor, dataRectangle);
                Texture2D _finalTexture = new Texture2D(device, final_descriptor);

                _stagingTexture.Device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(_stagingTexture, _finalTexture);
```

**My question is two fold:**

1. The DataRectangle uses IntPtr type while the pointer retrieved from
   the interface is Byte array.. Is this not a problem? OR does the
   pitch member in the DataRectangle address this? For now I casted
   byteArray to IntPtr.
2. Would this approach work? OR is there a better way to handle this?

Any pointers, suggestions or constructive criticisms would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

a while ago i was looking for the same and I come up with this function that always works fine for my use case

```
public static Texture2D CreateTexture2DFrombytes(Device device, byte[] RawData, int width, int height)
{
    Texture2DDescription desc;
    desc.Width = width;
    desc.Height = height;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource;
    desc.Usage = ResourceUsage.Immutable;
    desc.CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None;
    desc.Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None;
    desc.SampleDescription.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDescription.Quality = 0;
    DataStream s = DataStream.Create(RawData, true, true);
    DataRectangle rect = new DataRectangle(s.DataPointer, width * 4);
    Texture2D t2D = new Texture2D(device, desc, rect);
    return t2D;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek.. Really helpful.. Would you recommend the implementation i laid out concerning copying the resource from Texture1 to texture2? I feel there should be a straightforward way to do this..

Comment: you can try using  DeviceContext.CopySubresourceRegion(source, 0, null, destination, 0); where source and destination is texture2d